# Pandas TimeSeries into MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pandas, time-series

I have a general pandas TimeSeries which I want to store in MongoDB. The object ts looks like this:

```
>ts
2013-01-01 00:00:00     456.852985
2013-01-01 01:00:00     656.015532
2013-01-01 02:00:00     893.159043
...
2013-12-31 21:00:00    1116.526471
2013-12-31 22:00:00    1124.903600
2013-12-31 23:00:00    1065.315890
Freq: H, Length: 8760, dtype: float64
```

I want to convert this into an array of JSON documents, where one document is one row, to store it in MongoDB. Something like this:

```
[{"index": 2013-01-01 00:00:00, "col1": 456.852985},
{"index": 2013-01-01 01:00:00, "col1": 656.015532},
{"index": 2013-01-01 02:00:00, "col1": 893.159043},
...
]
```

I've ben looking into the TimeSeries.to_json() 'orient' options but I can't see they way of getting this format. Is there an easy way of performing this operation in pandas or should I look for a way of creating this structure using an external JSON library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make it a frame with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) so as to use the [record orient of `to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
In [11]: df = s.reset_index(name='col1')

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
                 index        col1
0  2013-01-01 00:00:00  456.852985
1  2013-01-01 01:00:00  656.015532
2  2013-01-01 02:00:00  893.159043

In [13]: df.to_json(orient='records')
Out[13]: '[{"index":"2013-01-01 00:00:00","col1":456.852985},{"index":"2013-01-01 01:00:00","col1":656.015532},{"index":"2013-01-01 02:00:00","col1":893.159043}]'
```

Comment: Performing a reset_index() to convert from a TimeSeries into a DataFrame looks like a extremely expensive operation though. Is there a way to improve the efficiency?

Comment: @MonkeyButter This might be a good feature request on to_json (to have this orient for Series), that'll be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Using one row per document will be pretty inefficient - in space and query performance terms.

If you have flexibility on the schema, we've open sourced a library for storing pandas (and other numeric data) easily in MongoDB:

https://github.com/manahl/arctic